# Access Workplace (Internal facebook) data through API

Tags: python, facebook-workplace

I am trying to access our company's workplace (Internal Facebook) data through an API call. I have created an access token and I am trying with this API call, which accesses the company's public Facebook page. Rather, I need to access the internal workplace (Facebook) page.

This is the api call I am trying with:

```
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/company_name/feed/?access_token=fhdsfkjhaslkfhaskjfhdskf14987294mcjiyrwiqwrwqmnmbvmv
```

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you have to access to your Workplace instance via API is using the Graph API with the token generated from the custom integration in the Workplace admin dashboard